# Well known over 50 years ago; How could it issue?

Tags: prior-art

In reference to the patent: [US8227460](https://www.google.com/patents/US8227460)

US 2836615 is for a method for removing methylene blue from monomers Col.1 line 35 "Methylene blue is known to be a ueeful polymerization inhibitor for acrylic monomers."
Col.1 line 35 "Methylene blue is known to be a useful polymerization inhibitor for acrylic monomers."

Answer (score 2):

Claim 1 of that patent is -

> 1. A composition consisting essentially of:
>      a polymerizable compound having two or more conjugated unsaturated groups and comprising a core having 2 to 10 chains, said conjugated unsaturated groups being attached to any of the last 20 atoms of the chains;
>      and methylene blue in a concentration of 10 to 5000 ppm to prevent premature polymerization of the polymerizable compound.

It is a claim for a composition, not a method. The specification your quoted from explains the invention, the claims define what is actually protected. The other claims are dependent claims that further narrow claim 1.

Comment: US2836615 is a method for removing methylene blue and US8227460 is a compound which employs methylene blue. I can't see why the first reads on the second.